# librxtxSerial.so long double restrict

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I'm trying to read data from serial port with rxtx library (https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx) on Ubuntu 14.04 (x64). I have simple java applet build with and running on java 1.6 (was trying 1.8 with the same result).

- Port init class - http://pastebin.com/KZFfGKtE
- Listener class - http://pastebin.com/D4Wq0ctT

And when listener wants to read input it crashes with the following error.

```
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
RXTX Warning:  Removing stale lock file. /var/lock/LCK..ttyUSB0
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f90ac2e2462, pid=6721, tid=140259339552512
#
# JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x6462]  long double restrict+0x52
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/etxzay/IdeaProjects/Solenoid/hs_err_pid6721.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.

Process finished with exit code 134
```

Looks like it's a kind of native RXTX library (librxtxSerial.so) problem. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... use JSSC (https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector). It works.